# OpenGL Certain VertexBuffers Not Rendering

Tags: c#, opengl, voxel

I have encountered a strange error whilst building a voxel-based game. This video best shows what's happening: https://youtu.be/CKhf7SbBKGU

I am creating this game in C# with a separate library managing the OpenGL bindings (OpenGLContext)

The map is divided into chunks of 32 x 32 x 32 voxels, and each are drawn through separate glDrawArrays calls (ctx.DrawArrays):

```
public void RenderMapNear(OpenGLContext ctx, List<Int3> nearPositions)
{
    mapShader.UseProgram();
    foreach (Int3 c in nearPositions)
    {
        m.data[c.X, c.Y, c.Z].vertexBuffer.Bind();
        ctx.DrawArrays(DrawMode.TriangleStrip, 0, m.data[c.X, c.Y, c.Z].vertexBuffer.Length);
    }
}
```

The vertexBuffer's Bind function is as follows:

```
public void Bind()
{
    ctx.BindBuffer(BufferID.Array, _bufferHandle);
    ctx.BindVertexArray(_arrayHandle);

    if (_used > 0 && _dirty)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            // _data is an array of BlockVertex, which contains a Vector3 (3 floats) for the vertex position and a uint for the vertex colour
            fixed (BlockVertex* p = _data)
            {
                 ctx.BufferData(BufferID.Array, (IntPtr)(_used * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BlockVertex))), (IntPtr)p, BufferUsage.StaticDraw);
            }
        }
        _dirty = false;
    }
}
```

However, there are only two chunks in the entire map that refuse to draw, with location (0,0,4) and (1,0,4).

OpenGL and GLSL information is as follows:

```
OpenGL Version: 4.5.13521 Compatibility Profile Context 24.20.11016.4
ShadingLanguageVersion: 4.50
OpenGL Renderer: Radeon RX 580 Series
OpenGL Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oops, habit. Thank you

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by unbinding the VBO and VAO after initialising the vertex buffers and after each glDrawArrays call.